# Make UICollectionViewCell appear in center of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have some cells which are dynamically added to the `UICollectionView`. What I would like to do is change the inset of these cells so they appear in the center of the `UICollectionView`. This is because the more cells that are added the cell height changes (it is a single Row `UICollectionView`).

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView*)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    // This method is used to center when one tile is entered else use a standard no inset
    if (self.wordArray.count == 1) {
        CGFloat newWidth = (self.tileCollectionView.bounds.size.width - self.tileCollectionView.bounds.size.height);
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, (newWidth / 2), 0, (newWidth/2));
    } else {
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0); // top, left, bottom, right
    }
}
```

How do I get a reference to the `UICollectionViewCell` current height, for any of the cells as they are all shaped the same (just their height/width changes when more added to continue to fit to one row.

Once I have the reference to the cell height, I can add something like:
self.tileCollectionView.bounds.size.height - CELLHEIGHT /2 --  to use as the inset for the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a grid-style layout, I'd try this method:
[collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout/collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:)

You'll need to implement the UICollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate to do so. To get them to stack, set the minimum offsets to negatives the size of the cells themselves. This may take some trial and error.

Comment: Yes I already use this method to change the cell size. What I am trying to do is find out the cell size from another method, that in the question. How do I determine what the cell size is so I can work out the insets to make them center align within the collection views height?

Comment: You'll need to have a reference to the cell(or just its size) somewhere. I'd stick it in a variable for easy access.

Comment: Ok, Ill accept I just put a variable in the cell creation method to hold the size and used it later. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If all of your cells are the same size and assuming you are using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, you can use this to get their size:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
CGFloat width = flowLayout.itemSize.width;
CGFloat height = flowLayout.itemSize.height;
```

This is how I calculate my insets using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`:

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
    NSInteger numberOfCells = self.view.frame.size.width / flowLayout.itemSize.width;
    NSInteger edgeInsets = (self.view.frame.size.width - (numberOfCells * flowLayout.itemSize.width)) / (numberOfCells + 1);
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, edgeInsets, 0, edgeInsets);
}
```

You'll also need to make sure to invalidate the layout when the screen rotates to make it calculate the new insets again:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
}
```